# How would you enter special characters into MySQL from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Effectively, what I am attempting to do is enter a string similar to this string
into [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) (it's one line, made into two for readability)

```
fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;
stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-  linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1
```

MySQL allows me to INSERT the string into the field using [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) and phpMyAdmin adds the field as (again one line, made into two for readability):

```
('fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-
linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1'' in ''field list')
```

With my PHP code I attempted to add the in field list part to my code as follows

```
$rectangle_array[$rstyle] = $rectangle_array[$rstyle] . "' in ''field list'";
$mysql_rectangle_table_entry = "INSERT INTO $mysql_table VALUES
                               ($rectangle_array[$rstyle], 'rect',
                               $rectangle_array[$rid], $rectangle_array[$rwidth],
                               $rectangle_array[$rheight], $rectangle_array[$rx],
                               $rectangle_array[$ry])";
$run = mysql_query($mysql_rectangle_table_entry) or die(mysql_error());
```

And upon running the code I receive the following error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;s' at line 1

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).  Also, each of those values should be enclosed in single quotes since they are strings (I think).

Comment: Stop using mysql_query and building SQL queries by mashing together strings for a start. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: print `$mysql_rectangle_table_entry;` and look for a syntax error or post it here

Comment: mireSVK, you were right on printing out the actual statement, one of the many reasons I love this site, you learn while you code :). drew010, the quotes around the string helped alot, and I am going to look into the mysql_real_escape_string. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments…

You could use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to escape any MySQL special characters before insertion.

For example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (string_column) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($string) .  "')";
```

Another option is to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with PHP's [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I didn't down vote but I'm going to upvote this answer because for the purpose of the question escaping the string is fine - however the OP should be aware of the vulnerabilities if the input is from an unknown end user -  [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ftw

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look either at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape special characters that might break your INSERT.